# Swift initialize tabBarController without presenting it

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

The initial view controller is the tab bar controller. The tab bar is created programmatically.

**Problem:**

I need to **load the TabBarViewController** **without presenting** it if the boolean value loggedIn == false.

On older devices, this code works fine to never show the TabBarViewController if the user is not logged in.

However, on newer/faster devices the tab bar flashes before presenting the LogInViewController().

```
final class TabBarViewController: UITabBarController {

// MARK: - Lifecycle

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    configureTabs()
    
}

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    
     if(!loggedIn){
        
        let loginVC = LogInViewController()
        loginVC.isModalInPresentation = true
        loginVC.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
        present(loginVC, animated: false)
        
     }
}

}
```

What is the best work around to still load the TabBarViewController but not show it if I need to present a new VC.

Comment: Lots of approaches to this, but a couple things you could try. 1) move `super.viewDidAppear(animated)` *after* your `if` block (don't know if that will make a difference); 2) move `configureTabs()` out of `viewDidLoad()` and into an `else` block for your logged in test in `viewDidAppear`, i.e. `if (!loggedIn) { ... } else { configureTabs() }`

Comment: Did you try to test login and set view hidden in viewWillAppear ?

Comment: @PtitXav yes it does not work because i need to present new VC after tabviewcontroller is loaded. So essentially i need to load the tabviewcontroller without showing it. I cant seem to find a proper way to do it when hiding the viewcontroller view.